# onchange doesn't work automatically when an input changes

Tags: javascript, onchange, calculation

I m writing a javascript to calculate a price based on user input and Total price based on calculated price. I don't want to put onchange="Total();" into user input because I want the Total function distinguish the value change of price input automatically. Is there a way to do that?

```
 <html>
  user input:<input type="text" id="user-input"  onchange="price();"><br>

  price:<input type="text" id="calculation"  onchange="Total();" readonly>
  <br>


  Total:<input type="text" id="result" readonly><br>

  </html>

          <script>
         function price() {

        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('user-input').value),
            b = document.getElementById('calculation');


            b.value = a + 10;

               }



       function Total() {
           var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('calculation').value),
               c = document.getElementById('result');

               c.value = b*2;
                  }

                   </script>
```

Comment: Your question is totally misleading if one looks at your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/404na6nc/), in base of your code and applied a event between two inputs. The dispatch, of second input is like manually, because is readonly.

```
function price() {

        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('user-input').value),
            b = document.getElementById('calculation');


            b.value = a + 10;
            if (b.onchange) 
                            b.onchange();
               }



       function Total() {
       console.log('binded');
           var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('calculation').value),
               c = document.getElementById('result');

               c.value = b*2;
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform all the calculations in `price()` instead of having separate `Total()`. Since both `price` and `result` are `readonly`, user can't really change the values in them. Hence, just move the code from `Total()` to `price()` and it will work for you. Below is the updated code:

```js
function price() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('user-input').value),
    b = document.getElementById('calculation'),
    c = document.getElementById('result')
  b.value = a + 10;
  c.value = b.value * 2;
}
```

```html
user input:<input type="text" id="user-input" onchange="price();"><br> price:

<input type="text" id="calculation" readonly>
<br> Total:
<input type="text" id="result" readonly><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Jquery try using a delegate**. Here is a simple example.

The below is the html.

```
user input:<input type="text" id="user-input">
```

The below is the javascript.

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "#user-input", "onchange", function() {
  //your code here.
});
```

My answer will just make the `onchange()` event fire, the rest of the logic you have to code.

**This is another example using JavaScript. I have tried and it is working fine.**

The below is the html code.

```
<input type="text" id="userinput" onchange="price();">
```

The below is the JavaScript function.

```
function price()
{
    //your code here.
}
```

Comment: You sure the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: is there a same javascript code for this "delegate"?

Comment: I'm assuming that he is using JQuery.